# conversion of bytearray into string in python

Tags: python, sql

**Background Info:** I want to pass a string as a parameter in sql query:

```
sqlq="""select reaction_time from table5 where sessionID=%s"""
```

My data is in the form of bytearray like (this sessionID is also retrieved from database)

```
{u'sessionID': bytearray(b'001f6340f7651db3e289d348de75f9bb')}
```

**Problem:** How can I convert it into string so it looks like the following? `'001f6340f7651db3e289d348de75f9bb'`

Answer (score 0):

In 3.X:

```
>>> d = {u'sessionID': bytearray(b'001f6340f7651db3e289d348de75f9bb')}
>>> my_string = d[u"sessionID"].decode()
>>> my_string
'001f6340f7651db3e289d348de75f9bb'
```

Possibly you are now thinking "I tried this, but because I'm using Python 2.7, the output is `u'001f6340f7651db3e289d348de75f9bb'`. I don't want that 'u' at the front. How do I make it an 8 bit string, not a Unicode string?". Conversion between a 2.7 bytearray and a 2.7 string is straightforward -- both types are 8 bit, so no decoding is necessary. A simple `str()` call is sufficient:

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>py -2
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {u'sessionID': bytearray(b'001f6340f7651db3e289d348de75f9bb')}
>>> my_string = str(d[u"sessionID"])
>>> my_string
'001f6340f7651db3e289d348de75f9bb'
```

Comment: yes @Kevin it works for converting a one sessionID into string. but if i have an array of sessionIDs then how to convert this array. as I fetched these sessionIDs from another table. (sqlselect = """SELECT DISTINCT sessionID FROM another_table""")